# Date Time difference in minutes in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, date

i am using following method to get date time difference in minutes it giving me negative value .

I am using following code :

```
NSCalendar *gregorian = [[NSCalendar alloc]
                         initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian];

NSUInteger unitFlags = NSCalendarUnitMonth | NSCalendarUnitDay | NSCalendarUnitMinute;

NSDateComponents *components = [gregorian components:unitFlags
                                            fromDate:dt2
                                              toDate:dt1 options:0];
NSInteger months = [components month];
NSInteger days = [components day];
NSInteger minutes = [components minute];

NSLog(@"months %ld",(long)months);
NSLog(@"days %ld",(long)days);
NSLog(@"minutes %ld",(long)minutes);

int res = (int)minutes;
NSLog(@"int minutes %d",res);

return res;
```

I want to calculate difference between these two below date in minutes:

- date1:2016-11-23 07:39:44 +0000
- date2:2016-11-23 08:13:44 +0000

As a result I'm getting `-34`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to replace with this :

```
NSDateComponents *components = [gregorian components:unitFlags
                                            fromDate:dt1
                                              toDate:dt2 options:0];
```

Answer (score 0):

`fromDate` will contain an earlier date and `toDate` will contains later date in `NSDateComponents` you are passing it wrongly change this

```
NSDateComponents *components = [gregorian components:unitFlags
                                            fromDate:dt2
                                              toDate:dt1 options:0];
```

to this

```
NSDateComponents *components = [gregorian components:unitFlags
                                            fromDate:dt1
                                              toDate:dt2 options:0];
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't know which date is former, just return absolute value of difference.   That will always give you positive value.

```
return abs(res);
```